# (Griffiths E&M problem 1.10) Why components of vector doesn't transform under translation of co-ordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors

What I thought is that, when we translate the coordinate system, y component of the vector must be increased or decreased depending on the value of a,  as the origin is changed and hence we have to measure the components respective to new origin.

But author clearly says that if we consider the same vector from a new origin, then it is a completely different vector.

But if we consider the previous question problem 1.9 then, even after rotation about an axis , we consider those changes in the components of vectors.

How these two things are different?

Please also suggest me any comprehensive text on vector transformation that can help me in understanding these things more clearly as I had seen many books but I hadn't found any book with much details of vector transformation.

Answer (score 2):

Vector spaces don't have an origin, but they have a null vector, $\vec 0$, satisfying:

$$ \vec a + \vec 0 = \vec a $$

for all $\vec a$ in the vector space. But $\vec 0$ is *not* a place.

Affine spaces have an origin ${\bf O}$ so that an origin plus a vector defines any point:

$${\bf P} = {\bf O} + \vec p $$

and difference between two points is a vector:

$${\bf P}_2-{\bf P}_1=\vec p_2-\vec p_1\equiv\vec r_{(2,1)} $$

If you change the origin ${\bf O}\rightarrow {\bf O'}$ then you change the vector associated with a point:

$$ {\bf P} = {\bf O} + \vec p={\bf O'} + \vec p'$$

In terms of physics, the point in space is what's invariant. The description of that point as a vector depends on the choice of origin.

Physics equations involving vectors, e.g.:

$$ \vec F=q(\vec E+\vec v\times \vec B)$$

are manifestly covariant under rotations. In this case, there is no origin, so translation aren't something to consider.

Physics equation involving positions are best expressed with the vector difference in positions:

$$ \vec F_{21} = \frac 1{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{q_1q_2}{|\vec r_2-\vec r_1|^2}$$

though sometimes that is simplified to just use $\vec r$, which can lead to confusion if you consider it as a point in an affine space: ${\bf r}={\bf O}+\vec r$

Comment: I was unable to understand clearly what you said as I had recently started to study linear algebra. I am not familiar with the concepts of vector spaces and affine spaces.